# In PayPal IPN history shows "HTTP response code:406".

Tags: php, paypal

I am using PayPal API for payment process in my website. payment working fine with one server. But not working properly with another server. In Paypal the payment is failed and shows the below error in IPN history.
"HTTP Response code : 406" .

Comment: Please add code block of your Payment Form here.

Answer (score 0):

IPN History has nothing to do with a payment failing.  If the payment failed then no IPN would be triggered.  What you're seeing in IPN History would be for a completed transaction that triggered an IPN, but your IPN script failed to complete and returned a 406 error code back to PayPal's IPN server.

As for the payment failing, I'd need to see the button code or API request (whichever you're working with) to try and reproduce the problem and see if I can help you that way.  Again, though, don't get confused relating IPN to a failed payment.

There are unique cases where you could actually get an IPN from a failed payment (like a failed recurring payment, for example) but then IPN would show a 200 Success if your IPN script was good even though the payment failed, so you apparently have 2 separate issues going on here.